# Web crawler that can automatically add found URLS to a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, web-crawler

Title pretty much says it all, I'm after a web-crawler that can automatically add its findings to a database, does such thing exist or am I better making my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a ton of services that you can pay for to do this: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-web-crawling-services  But, if you're looking for free, you're probably best off making your own.

If you go the DIY route, take a look at Firebase databases: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ Firebase makes it really easy to create a database, setup rules, and do CRUD operations from a simple webapp without building out a custom backend.  It sounds like the perfect candidate for a small project like you described.

Additionally, if you're new to webcrawlers, take a look at Scrapy.  Of all of the scraping libs I've used, this one is one of the easiest to use for simple projects.

Answer (score 0):

[StormCrawler](http://stormcrawler.net) has a SQL module which allows to store the information about the URLs discovered in table. The [Cloudsearch tutorial](http://digitalpebble.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/index-web-with-aws-cloudsearch.html) is a bit dated but explains how to use StormCrawler with MySQL.